# How can i load negative values in a register - assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

say that i have the following code:

C++ code and inline assembly code below:

Equation:

```
X=40+5 
Y=3*12 ---> X=45 Y=36
```

Test

`if x < y - print
 x+y`

`else 
print x-y`

```
int main()
{   
 int x=5,y=3,z=0;
 x=x+40;
 y=y*12;
 if(x<y) //45<36 - cond. is NOT met
      z=x+y; 
 else
     z=x-y; 
 cout << "z:" << z << endl; // z=9
     x=5,y=3,z=0;
 __asm
 {
     pushad
         mov eax,0
         mov ebx,0
         mov eax,x
         add eax,40
         mov ebx,y
         imul ebx,12
         cmp eax,ebx
         jb First ;cond is NOT met
         jmp Second ;we jump to Second label
 First: add eax,ebx
         mov z,eax
 Second: sub eax,ebx
         mov z,eax
     popad

 }
 cout << "z:" << z << endl; //z=9
 return 0;
}
```

Both results produce z=9,but if i change y=-3 in the C++ and assembly code respectively
(`int x=5,y=-3,z=0;` AND in `x=5,y=-3,z=0;`) i must get z=81 ,but the output is z=45 from the inline assembly,so i can't load the neg value(-3) in the ebx register properly...
My question is how can i load -3 in ebx ,so that i get 45-(-36)=81 ?

Comment: "mov ebx, -3"? Or am I missing something here...

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you have is that `jb` uses an unsigned comparison; you probably want to use `jl` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues - one is, as others have pointed out, that you've used a branch instruction based on an unsigned comparison.

The other is that, after executing the code in `First`, you then execute the code in `Second`. You'd usually want to have an unconditional `jmp` to after `Second`. At the moment, you add and then immediately subtract again.

So you might want:

```
        cmp eax,ebx
        jge Second ;cond is not met (I've removed one branch and reversed the test)
First:  add eax,ebx
        jmp Store
Second: sub eax,ebx
Store:  mov z,eax ;shared by both paths
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JL` instead of `JB`. One is signed compare, the other is unsigned compare.

Comment: Thanks guys!Appreciate your responses!